# Bad indentation vim from the clipboard

Tags: vim, indentation, vi

Update: thank all of you, I fixed it.
We have to use this in the .vimrc file.

`set pastetoggle=<F2>`

---

I'm still new using vim, when I try to paste something from the clipboard, vim does a bad indentation.
Example:
VIM:

```
line
 line
  line
```

Original:

```
line
line
line
```

Now, its important to say that I'm using the new terminal in windows, using powershell.
Thank you.

Comment: Not really a programming question. Might be better suited for [vi.se].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp vim is one of "Software development tools". So it fits the website perfectly.

Comment: Please post your code in a code fence. Thanks! Code in images is not encouraged.

Comment: Do not put the answer in your question, you can answer your own question. Also with `set pastetoggle=<F2>` you still have to press F2 before pasting and press it again after the paste to get automatic indentation back. Check if you can get bracketed paste to work in power shell. This seems to be [an open issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/1471).

Answer (score 1):

you can try to enable the `paste` option:

```
set paste
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which OS and which terminal emulator you are in, you might be able to use bracketed paste mode. Bracketed paste is available by default in vim since version 8.
I had an issue setting it up on my system and here is [a setup that user938271 suggested me on vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25346/6671). Add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Activate bracketed paste in tmux
if &term =~ "screen"
  let &t_BE = "\e[?2004h"
  let &t_BD = "\e[?2004l"
  exec "set t_PS=\e[200~"
  exec "set t_PE=\e[201~"
endif
```

Replace `"screen"` by the output of:

```
echo  $TERM
```

from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to set the filetype beforehand because of the level of indentation and its rules change for different file types. For example:

```
:setf java
```

or

```
:setf c
```